# How to strip a css class using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slider image wrapped in an href and it adds a class to the href.. I can see it when i inspect element but I don't see it when I have the file open in my IDE.

```
<a href="champions.html" target="_blank" style="display: block;" class="imgLink"><img src="/slider-9.jpg" alt="Click To Register!" style="display:none;"></a>
```

The display block needs to be display:none; but I'm not sure how I can fix it...

When a slider image is not loaded with an href wrapped around the image... it looks like this:

```
<div class="sliderInner"><div class="mcSlc" style="left: auto; width: 960px; height: 400px; z-index: 1; position: absolute; opacity: 1; top: 0px; right: 0px; background: url(/slider-3.jpg) 0px 0% no-repeat;"></div></div>
```

I'm not sure why when it's wrapped in an href it changes to display:block;

Here is my css:

```
#slider a.imgLink, #slider .video {
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute;
    top:-30px;left:0px;border:0;padding:0;margin:0;
    width:100%;height:100%;
}
```

I tried just addding display:none;

Do I need to mark it as important after `display:none`? Additionally I tried doing it inline.. nothing seems to work.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So if you're not setting any inline styles, logically some JS did. *Do i need to mark it as important after display none?* have you tried?

Comment: Where are you setting the display to none? I can't see it in your CSS. BTW, you can use jQuery's ```hide``` method to force element not to display. I suspect you have a ```show``` method triggering somewhere and setting that ```display:block``` style

Comment: I took the display:none out of my css because it wasn't working and I have not tried using the important tag yet.. I'll try that now.

Comment: I was thinking maybe the .removeClass() method or the hide method but i'm not the best with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `$('.imgLink').removeClass();` ?